# Giving named variable to function dynamically

Tags: python

I have dictionaliy for variables of function.

```
x = {"reverberance":20,"hf_damping":10}
```

Now I want to give the contents of `x` to this funciton.

```
def reverb(self,
       reverberance=50,
       hf_damping=50,
       room_scale=100,
       stereo_depth=100,
       pre_delay=20,
       wet_gain=0,
       wet_only=False):
```

What I made for now is, but it doesn't work, because maybe `x[key]` have to be converted to `str`? (but if not i can concatenate )

```
x = {"reverberance":20,"hf_damping":10}
arr = []
for key in x:
    arr.append(key + "=" + str(x[key]))


reverb(",".join(arr))
```

Comment: You can use `reverb(**x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just unpack kwargs directly:

```
x = {"reverberance":20,"hf_damping":10}

def reverb(
       reverberance=50,
       hf_damping=50,
       room_scale=100,
       stereo_depth=100,
       pre_delay=20,
       wet_gain=0,
       wet_only=False):
    return reverberance, hf_damping

reverb(**x) # returns (20,10)
```

Comment: `**` works perfect!! looks like a charm.